# Firebase Push notifications only showing "from" when sending to device group token

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a service for handling push notifications that integrates with Firebase cloud messaging. When I send a new message and specify a device token, it works fine. I get the notification title, body etc. However, when I specifiy a device group ID (which I get as a response when I register a new group with the device token), the device gets a notification, but it's blank - only showing the "from" field which is the sender ID. None of the notification title, body etc. show.

Code for message construction

```
func FcmNewMessage(title, body, collapseKey, token string) *messaging.Message {
    oneHour := time.Duration(1) * time.Hour
    message := &messaging.Message{
        Notification: &messaging.Notification{
            Title: title,
            Body:  body,
        },
        Android: &messaging.AndroidConfig{
            TTL:         &oneHour,
            CollapseKey: collapseKey,
        },
        APNS: &messaging.APNSConfig{
            Headers: map[string]string{
                "apns-collapse-id": collapseKey,
            },
        },
        Webpush: &messaging.WebpushConfig{
            Notification: &messaging.WebpushNotification{
                Icon: "https://my-server/icon.png",
            },
            Headers: map[string]string{
                "urgency": "high",
                "topic":   collapseKey,
            },
        },
        Token: token,
    }
    return message
}
```

As you can see above -  "token" argument can either be a device token or a device group notification key token. It's when the device group token is used that there is issues.

Below are the client notifications:

When using the device token:

```
{
  "from": "53xxxxxxxxxx",
  "priority": "high",
  "notification": {
    "title": "test",
    "body": "test",
    "icon": "https://my-server/icon.png"
  },
  "collapse_key": "collapseMe"
}
```

When using device group token:

```
{
  "from": "53xxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

I should also mention that when a device group token is used, the response I get from FCM is:

```
projects/projectid-123/messages/
```

So there is no message ID at the end. Normally the response would be:

```
projects/projectid-123/messages/<messageId>
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: I've added the message constructor and the responses. The only thing that ever changes on the Send() is the token within the message.

Comment: Dude your question solved my issue! :D

Comment: That's great! What was the solution? I forgot to update this question with the answer I found, which was that `device group tokens` were no longer supported. They were a feature of the v1 API, but are no longer used now.

Answer (score 1):

Device group tokens were no longer supported. They were a feature of the v1 API, but are no longer used now, which is why this was not working. The Firebase docs aren't great and it took some serious digging to find this out.